# Do standard hard drives release any gases whatsoever as they operate?

Tags: hard-drive

I read somewhere once that hard drives with moving parts release gases as they operate. The article claimed that these gases could be harmful, and make having a laptop on your lap unhealthy.

Is it a myth that *regular* laptop hard drives (with moving parts) release any amount of any gases as they operate, or is this somehow true, whether or not it's healthy? Was it ever true?

As far as I know, there aren't any chemical reactions that might create gas involved in the functioning of regular hard drives. Tell me if I'm wrong.

I read the article some time ago, but I'm not sure where it went. Also, the fact that no one else is saying this (I searched for a good while and found nothing close) has me very suspicious.

Comment: What gases are released entirely depend on the HDD.  More recent models of high capacity mechanical drive contain helium which is harmless.  Of course if the drive's case is leaking gases the drive itself likely isn't even functional.

Comment: Is this just a way to ask if hard drives fart?

Comment: This would definitely make using your laptop in the car whilst it is in the garage with the doors closed & the engine running a most unhealthy proposition...

Comment: @Ramhound - I've just read http://www.howtogeek.com/127433/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-do-not-cover-this-hole-hole-on-hard-drives/ and most HDDs have a small breather hole that allows air pressure equilibrium. The argument, then, would be (apart from disks designed for high air pressure environments - which would be sealed/have gas sealed in) why would standard disks contain gas if the breather hole/filter allows air in/out to maintain pressure equilibrium?

Comment: @BigChris - I did not know that.  Of course helium would raise, so it would difficult, to let helium be replaced with a heaver gas like Oxygen within the semi-sealed system.  My original comments, if the drive is actually leaking gas, it is going to cause major problems.

Comment: I doubt that they release anything in any larger amount than any operating electronics. I mean, all electronics have more or less harmful compounds in their parts some of which do get released in the air and heat aggravates this, but I'd be more worried about the whole laptop than just the HDD.